# Do your 'fetch as google bot' allowances refresh?

Tags: google, google-search-console, fetch-as-google

in google webmaster tools you can fetch as google bot - which you can do 500 times, and you also have submit to index that you can do 10 times, do these allowances refresh or are they for the life of the site. ie, once you've used them all up thats it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Google Webmaster Tools help](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587), these limits are **per week**.

> You can use this tool to fetch up to 500 URLs a week per Webmaster
>   Tools account.
>
> If Googlebot can successfully fetch your page, you can submit that
>   page to the Google index. Just click Submit to Google index. You can
>   submit either the URL itself (limit of 500 URLs per week per Webmaster
>   Tools account), or the URL and all pages linked from it (limit of 10
>   per week per Webmaster Tools account).

Answer (score 0):

To update the answer above, it's now 10 full re-crawls (URL and linked pages) per *month*, not per week.

> If Googlebot can successfully fetch your page, you can submit that page to the Google index. Just click Submit to Google index. You can submit either the URL itself (limit of 500 URLs per week per Webmaster Tools account), or the URL and all pages linked from it (limit of **10 per month** per Webmaster Tools account).